# Phonegap android unable to upload image using fileTransfer

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to capture an image using the camera and upload it to my AJAX endpoint. I've confirmed that this endpoint can accept the file (I created a test HTML file on my desktop that sends a form with an image in it). I'm using Cordova (phonegap) 1.7.0, and am trying to get the fileTransfer() to work. Here is the link for the documentation that I followed:

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_file_file.md.html#FileTransfer

The success callback triggers, but no $_FILES data is to be found on the endpoint.

I then found this article:

http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/25/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap/

Which suggested using `options.chunkedMode = false`. Now the upload takes an age and a half, before eventually failing with an error code of 3, which I believe is `FileError.ABORT_ERR`.

Am I missing something?

My code from the app below:

```
     navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){           
        console.log('take success! uploading...');
        console.log(imageURI);
        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = 'file';
        options.fileName = 'spot_image.jpeg';
        options.mimeType = 'image/jpeg';
        var params = new Object();
        params.spot_id = 1788;
        params.param2 = 'something else';
        options.params = params;        
        options.chunkedMode = false;
        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI,serverURL + '/ajax.php?fname=appuploadspotimage',function(r){
            console.log('upload success!');
            console.log(r.responseCode);
            console.log(r.response);
            console.log(r.bytesSent);
        },function(error){
            console.log('upload error')
            console.log(error.code);
        },options,true);
        console.log('after upload');



    },function(message){
       console.log('fail!');
       console.log(message);
    },{ 
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    });
```

`serverURL` is defined as the domain for my AJAX endpoint, which has been whitelisted in cordova.xml.

I've seen a number of questions here in SO regarding this, which varying opinions as to whether chunkedMode should be used. Anyone having this issue as well?

Am trying this on a Samsung Galaxy S, running ICS.

May the person who helps me solve this issue mysteriously inherit a beer factory.

Comment: Could you check in your server what post params is it receiving? I had a similar problem, and finally found out that what was happening was that I wasn't sending the options object correctly

Comment: @davids Do you mean checking the `$_POST` variable in the server? I tried that and I get an empty array. I tried using `$_REQUEST` as well, just to check, and only the `fname` parameter that I supplied in the url is there. `$_FILES` turns up an empty array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not use imageUri that you get from camera success callback in FileTransfer upload method, you have to first resolve uri as a filename like this:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(function(imageURI){

      window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageUri, function(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.file(function(fileObj) {

                var fileName = fileObj.fullPath;

                //now use the fileName in your method
                //ft.upload(fileName ,serverURL + '/ajax.php?fname=appuploadspotimage'...);

            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Hey there DZL. I'm not actually working on this app anymore, but thanks for the code! I'll save this snippet and give it a try when I come across this again. Thanks :) Am marking your answer as accepted anyway.

Comment: No problem, I was struggling with this same problem recently and it took me a lot of time to figure it out.

Comment: And the answer was very usefull to others (among me :) ), thanks

Comment: Should this be `resolveLocalFileSystemURL` (instead of URI)? And/or, have things changed?

Comment: @DZL i am also facing the similar issue but not able to fix it. can you please check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514847/

Comment: As of 1.0.0 or newer version of File, you should invoke `fileEntry.toURL()` instead of `fileObj.fullPath`. Also note that `resolveLocalFileSystemURI` is deprecated and you should be using `resolveLocalFileSystemURL`

Answer (score 0):

After puzzling a bit, it seems to me you can use the image uri directly....

see my answer here: (this works for me on android):

[android phonegap camera and image uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14447336/android-phonegap-camera-and-image-uploading)

Comment: Maybe they fixed it in the new cordova release to automatically convert uri to the file name but in 'cordova-2.2.0.js', the one that I am using I could upload the file, but I couldn't open it on the server. The only way I could open the file was to first call 'window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI' and than transfer it with the file name returned from 'resolveLocalFileSystemURI'.

Comment: Ok, that might be the case!