# Phonegap on Android: Can't access file from camera

Tags: android, cordova, file-access

For quite some time, I use Phonegap for our app that takes pictures and finally sends them to the server. Until recently, we used Phonegap 1.4 and everything went well.

Now I first switched to 2.2 then 2.5, but am always having problems in accessing the picture after it has been taken. The camera is responding with the file URI, but when I try to access the file, I always get an error 5.

```
fileSystem.root.getFile(file, {create: false}, ideaCommitCopyFileEntryToLocal, failOpenFile);
```

Now I am looking for advice, what is going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried resolving the file URI to file name, check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754299/phonegap-android-unable-to-upload-image-using-filetransfer/14220608#14220608)

Comment: Where are you saving this file? is it in any directory? probably you might want to get the directory first and then get the file:// Get the data directory, creating it if it doesn't exist.
dataDir = fileSystem.root.getDirectory("data", {create: true});

// Create the lock file, if and only if it doesn't exist.
lockFile = dataDir.getFile("lockfile.txt", {create: true, exclusive: true});